# Extract scss into multiple files using extract-text-webpack-plugin?

Tags: sass, webpack

My folder structure is like this

```
|
|-scss/
    |-main1.scss
    |-main2.scss
```

Is it possible to use extract-text-webpack-plugin to extract these two entry points two separate files?

Currently, I'm getting it as a single file.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the two entry points in your webpack config like so:

```
entry: {
    main1: __dirname + '/src/main1.js',
    main2: __dirname + '/src/main2.js',
},
ouput: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: '[name].js'
}
```

I assume your `main1.scss` is imported in the main1.js file, and `main2.scss` is imported in `main2.js`.

You can then use the `[name]` placeholder on the extract-text-webpack-plugin, which should create a separate output file for each entry point:

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
]
```

This should output two separate css files for you: `main1.css` and `main2.css`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I have 2 scss files, core.scss and core2.scss but I have a single code entry point, index.js. Is it still possible to have 2 css files, so that one I can load synchronously and another in async mode?